# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when invoking mockstatic(staticclass.class)

Tags: powermock

I have a class called Test as follows

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Application.class })

public class Test
{
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        Result res= mock(Result.class);
        mockStatic(Application.class);
        doNothing().when(Application.class, "getResult", res);
    }
}
```

Here getResult is a void static method in Application class.
I'm getting following stacktrace at line  mockStatic(Application.class);

LOG:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   Application$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$715802ad Stacktrace
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   Application$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$715802ad     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor171.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)   at
>   org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
>     at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
>     at Test.setUp(Test.java:03)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

is it a problem in powermock?

Comment: Your problem is that you think "powermock is part of the solution space" ;-) But too often, it is more "part of the problem space". My 2 cent: unless you need powermock to test legacy or 3rd party code that you are not allowed to modify; it is **always** better to improve the code under test to not need PowerMock. So instead of investing time into fixing obscure bizarre PowerMock problems ... I personally prefer to fix my code instead.

Comment: @GhostCat, Thanks for your feedback. Here I have posted a sample scenario but I'm actually working on a 3rd party code where I don't have any other choice except to use powermock. Could you pls help me in resolving the error using powermock

Comment: Not really; thing is: I gave up on PowerMock exactly for such problems. The one thing I would try (although I dont think it will change anything) - see if it makes any difference if you dont use the curly braces for PrepareForTest ... you only need those when you have multiple entries. But well, that shouldnt matter.

Comment: @GhostCat; actually i have many other classes to be included in  PrepareForTest . To make it simple,i deleted other classes.

Comment: Sorry, not much of an idea then. Besides: stepping back, and trying to reduce the content of your failing test until it does not fail any more. Is there a chance to rework YOUR code that uses that 3rd party libraries?

Comment: If getResult is the static method and if it is part of Result class, then shouldn't you prepare Result class for test instead of Application class Or is my understanding wrong ?